# MySql query not being executed

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently downloaded and modified a IPN listener, and I want it to do something more than log the donation, but to add points to a user. However it doesn't do *anything* even though I am sure my code is correct. The first Mysql_Query works and logs the donation but the second one doesnt. I need help, please!

```
    //require paypal, connection and config

    $p = new paypal_class;
    $p->paypal_url = $payPalURL;

    if ($p->validate_ipn()) 
    {
        if($p->ipn_data['payment_status']=='Completed')
        {
            $amount = $p->ipn_data['mc_gross'] - $p->ipn_data['mc_fee'];

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO dc_donations( transaction_id, donor_email, amount, original_request)
                         VALUES (
                                 '".esc($p->ipn_data['txn_id'])."',
                                 '".esc($p->ipn_data['payer_email'])."',
                                  ".(float)$amount.",
                                 '".esc(http_build_query($_POST))."'
                                 )");
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO dc_credits (SteamID,Credits) 
                         VALUES ('TEST','1000')");
        }
    }

    function esc($str)
    {
        global $link;
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str,$link);
    }
```

btw, If you need further code than I will add it

Comment: Try something like `$query = "INSERT ..."; $r = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);`

Comment: Also post the structure of the tables.

Comment: My (very, very) wild guess is that `STEAMID` is a primary key and query fails the second time you try to put a row with the same value (`TEST`) in the table, or some other problem with the Primary key of `dc_credits`.

Comment: What happens? What doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: It doesn't insert the values. I got no errors either.

Comment: Did you try the query in phpmyadmin or the CLI? What happened?

Comment: Have you tried running `INSERT INTO dc_credits (SteamID,Credits) 
                         VALUES ('TEST','1000')` directly in MySQL? Does it work?

Comment: Change the order of the queries in your code! Maybe the first query works only partially?

Comment: $p and $str are bad variable name, esc is a bad method name, make your code as readable as possible!

Comment: Reduce the code to the minimum and test again, use only the one query, reduce the one query, reduce more. Turn your error reporting to the max! Maybe passing a string '1000' to that table isn't correct?

Comment: Can you try with `mysql_error()`, as my first comment, or just echo `mysql_error()` after the query runs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the 2nd mysql_query first so that it gets executed first and if there is error, you can see the error without inserting to the other table.